# Java Equivalent for Numpy.arange

Tags: java, python, numpy

Is there a java equivalent for the Numpy library's numpy.arange function?

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? Why can't you just use a for loop?

Comment: Ya I just ended up using a for loop. Thanks tho.